# Flutter How to show all pages in Indexed Stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I'm trying to select the pages with the dropdown menu and show the selected page. However, I want to show all pages by adding one more option to display all pages. If you could help with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it

My code:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: Get.width >= 390.w
                    ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 250.w, right: 24.w)
                    : EdgeInsets.only(left: 250.w, right: 24.w),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                      hint: Text(
                        controller.selectedValue,
                        style: AppTextStyle()
                            .getSfProDisplayMedium_H6(AppColors.BLACK),
                      ),
                      value: controller.selectedValue,
                      items: controller.cardlist.map((String val) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                          value: val,
                          child: Text(
                            val,
                            style: AppTextStyle()
                                .getSfProDisplayMedium_H6(AppColors.BLACK),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? item) {
                        if (item == 'Tümü') {
                          controller.subPageId = 0;
                        }
                        if (item == 'Duyurular') {
                          controller.subPageId = 1;
                        }
                        if (item == 'Anketler') {
                          controller.subPageId = 2;
                        }
                        if (item == 'Sponsorlar') {
                          controller.subPageId = 3;
                        }
                        controller.update();
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          IndexedStack(
            index: controller.subPageId,
            children: [
              PostCardWidget(),
              QuestionnaireCardWidget(),
              SponsoredCardWidget()
            ],
          ),
```

I want to show three pages when 'Tümü' option is selected

Answer (score 0):

navigator manages its routes using strings, which means that we will need to have a way to convert your enum (which I renamed to Page) to Strings. We can use describeEnum for that and put that into an extension:

```
enum Page { screenDashboard, screenProfile, screenSearch }

extension on Page {
  String get route => describeEnum(this);
}
```

Now, you can get the string representation of a page using e.g. Page.screenDashboard.route.

Furthermore, you want to map your actual pages to your fragment widgets, which you can do like this:

```
class MainBodyApp extends HookWidget {
  final Map<Page, Widget> _fragments = {
    Page.screenDashboard: DashboardPage(),
    Page.screenProfile: UserProfilePage(),
    Page.screenSearch: SearchPage(),
  };
  ...
```

To access the Navigator, we need to have a GlobalKey. Usually we would have a StatefulWidget and manage the GlobalKey like that. Since you want to use flutter_hooks, I opted to use a GlobalObjectKey instead:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final navigatorKey = GlobalObjectKey<NavigatorState>(context);
  ...
```

Now, you can use navigatorKey.currentState anywhere in your widget to access this custom navigator. The full Navigator setup looks like this:

```
Navigator(
  key: navigatorKey,
  initialRoute: Page.screenDashboard.route,
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    final pageName = settings.name;

    final page = _fragments.keys.firstWhere((element) => describeEnum(element) == pageName);

return MaterialPageRoute(settings: settings, builder: (context) => _fragments[page]);
```

},
)
As you can see, we pass the navigatorKey created before and define an initialRoute, making use of the route extension we created. In onGenerateRoute, we find the Page enum entry corresponding to the route name (a String) and then return a MaterialPageRoute with the appropriate _fragments entry.

To push a new route, you simply use the navigatorKey and pushNamed:

```
onPressed: () => navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(Page.screenDashboard.route),
```